# Iterating and retrieving metadata of all objects in Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS Java SDK to interact with S3. I want to iterate through all the objects in the storage and retrieve metadata of each object. I can iterate through the objects using lists as:

```
ObjectListing  list= s3client.listObjects("bucket name");
```

But I am able to retrieve only summaries through the object in the list. Instead of summary I need metadata of each object, like the one provided by `getObjectMetadata()` method in S3Object class. How do I get that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get four default metadata from objectSummary that returned from lisObject : `Last Modified, Storage Type, Etag and Size.`

**To get metadata of objects**, you need to perform [HEAD object](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--amazon-s3-objects-head-object.html) request on object or you call following method on your object :

```
GetObjectMetadataRequest(String bucketName, String key)
```

Look at this:

```
 ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
                    .withBucketName(bucketName);
            ObjectListing objectListing;
            do {
                objectListing = s3client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
                for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary
                        : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
                    /** Default Metadata **/
                    Date dtLastModified = objectSummary.getLastModified();
                    String sEtag = objectSummary.getETag();
                    long lSize = objectSummary.getSize();
                    String sStorageClass = objectSummary.getStorageClass();
                    /** To get user defined metadata **/
                    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = s3client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, objectSummary.getKey());
                    Map userMetadataMap = objectMetadata.getUserMetadata();
                    Map rowMetadataMap = objectMetadata.getRawMetadata();
                }
                listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker());
            } while (objectListing.isTruncated());
```

For more details on GetObjectMetadataRequest, look this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectMetadataRequest.html).

Comment: API v2 has `getObject` method which takes `GetObjectRequest` object and returns a `GetObjectResponse`. `GetObjectResponse#metadata` returns a `Map` for the metadata information.